# php name spelling correction from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, spell-checking

I have a database containing "FirstName - LastName - Company" from users

I'm looking for a spelling corrector to help me to do matching between data on a form and the database

Imagine I have "Luk - Vandbrol - Google" on my database... I want to be able to find this entry if i enter "Luc - Vandrol - Google"

Do you have anny known class that could help me?

Thanks

Comment: Don't look for something that will improve the spelling, improve your matching algorithms instead. Crap-name to good-name things, are worth the time if you're going to be at this for a decade but otherwise aren't necessarily worth the time investment.

Comment: why not do a google like entry?

Answer (score 1):

There is a component for PHP called "PHP Spell Check" which allows you to include spellcheck in your development.

You can test it and download it from http://www.phpspellcheck.com/